# newcommand that includes parse lines

Tags: macros, verse, parselines

I am trying to typeset a series of verses some which have long lines. I want the long lines to be indented when it overflows to the next line. The package `parselines` does serve the purpose nicely.

Here is the sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ a5paper, body={10cm,17cm}, centering ]{geometry}
\usepackage{parselines}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.65\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  \begin{parse lines}[\parindent 0pt]{\raggedright\hangindent1em\hangafter1 #1\par}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua At vero eos et
  accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  \end{parse lines}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua At vero eos et
  accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
  %
\end{minipage}
%

\end{document}
```

Since this has to be done many times, I thought of defining a macro for the same like:

```
\newcommand{\POEM}[2]{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.65\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  \begin{parse lines}[\parindent 0pt]{\raggedright\hangindent1em\hangafter1 #1\par}
  #1 
  \end{parse lines}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
  \vspace*{0pt}
  #2
\end{minipage}
%
}
```

The problem is `#1` of `parse lines` conflicts with the parameter of my macro. Can I avoid this?

If there are other methods/packages to achieve this, I would like some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems in your approach. Not only `#1` (which must be changed to `##1` inside another macro) but the `\obeylines` setting (which does the `parse lines` environment) must be done before the the data are read from the file, i.e. you cannot first read the data to the parameter and then use `\obeylines` (or `\begin{parse lines}`) in your macro.

I suggest to implement the `\POEM` macro using TeX primitives and basic macros only. There are three ideas

- the typesetting is done by `\hbox to\hsize{\vtop{...}\hfil\vtop{...}}`. These are primitive commands used instead `\begin{minipage}`, `\end{minipage}`.
- indentation in the first column is done using negative `\parindent` and the `\leftskip` primitive register is set for compensation.
- the first parameter is read after `\obeylines` is set. The parameter is in the format `{data}`, the first `{` is ignored by `\let\next=` and the last `}` works like `\endgroup`, it closes the currently open `\vtop`. Then the macro continues like `\POEMB` using `\aftergroup` primitive.

```
\def\POEM{\hbox to\hsize\bgroup
   \vtop\bgroup
   \hsize=.65\hsize
   \obeylines \raggedright \parindent=-1em \leftskip=1em
   \aftergroup\POEMB
   \let\next=%
}
\def\POEMB #1{\hfil 
   \vtop\bgroup
   \hsize=.3\hsize
   \parindent=0pt \emergencystretch=1em
   #1\par
   \egroup\egroup
}

\POEM {
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua At vero eos et
  accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. 
}{
  invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua At vero eos et
  accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and code. It works well.